# I cannot connect to ssh with vscode ( channel 4: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed )

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

i am trying to connect to my bluehost wordpress website through ssh but i get the error

`channel 4: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed`

i am able to connect through the terminal and it works but i cant use vscode

I tried to downgrade or upgrade the extension but still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
channel 4: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

This means that the local ssh process sent a request to the remote ssh server process requesting to open a channel, and the remote ssh process refused the request. If you're getting this with vscode while trying to use a remote access feature, it seems likely that ssh is trying to open a port forwarding channel, and the remote server is configured not to accept port forwarding requests.

You will need to alter the ssh server configuration on the remote system. If you don't have access to do that, you should contact the administrators for the remote system. There are two ways to disable port forwarding on the remote system:

1. The sshd [AllowTCPForwarding](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AllowTcpForwarding) option may be set not to permit forwarding.
2. If you're using an ssh key to authenticate to the remote system, the *authorized_keys* file entry for the ssh key that you're using may have the [no-port-forwarding](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#no-port-forwarding) or [restrict](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#restrict) options set.

Comment: apparently AllowTCPForwarding needs root access and root access needs a "premium plan" from my host. is there any other way i can connect with vscode?

Answer (score 1):

Allow "AllowTcpForwarding yes" in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Check also the conf files located in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf, these files are included at the start of the configuration file, so options set there will override those in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Afterwards restart sshd: `sudo systemctl restart sshd`